# Azure Serverless SQL - filtering on non partition columns performance

Tags: azure, serverless, partitioning, azure-synapse

I'm new to Azure. I understand the performance gain when you filter using filepath(n) or using wildcards on the file path

But I would know what is the performance when you query data filtering on others than the partition columns. How much slower could it be (compared to do it on partition columns)?

I suppose that the engine/synapse should scan all the files in all folders, and given that a serverless dataset can't have indexes, I also suppose it would be very slow (in comparison).

In order to improve performance, could a good practice be to organize files in many folders, say a "long" path pc1/.../pcN/**npc1/.../npcM**, where each **npc*** folder is a non parition column that I later filter on?

Could anyone give some insight or precise link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Consider the queries that you'll be running frequently and partition your data accordingly. If you have specific non-partition columns that you filter on regularly, you may want to consider restructuring your data to make those columns part of the partitioning scheme.

Organizing files into many subfolders based on non-partition columns (as you suggested with a "long" path pc1/.../pcN/npc1/.../npcM) could potentially improve performance for specific queries. However, this approach has limitations of complexity can become complex to manage. It may create more partitions than necessary, which might actually hinder performance in some cases. You'd have to carefully balance the granularity of the partitions with query patterns and data volume.

Also in serverless your cost if based on data reads, so you will definitely want to reduce the amount of data being read by avoiding scans as much as possible. Ensuring that only part of your data is read which is relevant for the query.

Scans are very costly in terms of performance. But actual scan performance will depend on how much data is required to be read.

**Edited to Update More Regarding Joins.**

Parquet is a columnar storage format. This means that reading a specific column's data across many rows is faster than reading many columns for a specific row. If your JOIN operation predominantly filters or scans specific columns, Parquet's structure will inherently provide some performance benefits.

When data is partitioned, the query engine can skip entire partitions that are irrelevant to a query. This is particularly beneficial for filter operations, not JOINs specifically. Partitioning on columns that you're joining on can improve performance if it allows the query engine to skip large amounts of irrelevant data

Comment: In the case of columns that relate to other table's IDs, could partitioning on that columns improve the performance of JOINs? (I mean, SQL Joins between parquet files on the datalake)

Comment: @Hernán updated answer to address question about Joins.